# PowerBI/DAX Calculate Dynamic Sum based of specific column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate a dynamic sum based on the value of a specific column in DAX/PowerBI:

data as table:

| YEAR_CW | YEAR_CW_LY | AMOUNT_NET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 2021-01 | 76.47 |
| 2023-01 | 2022-01 | 342.53 |
| 2023-01 | 2022-01 | 325 |
| 2023-01 | 2022-01 | 111 |
| 2023-01 | 2022-01 | 629.25 |
| 2023-01 | 2022-01 | 196.56 |
| 2022-01 | 2021-01 | 34.2 |

The aim is to sum AMOUNT_NET for last year's calendar week:
[image]

so far I have tried:

```
AMOUNT_NET_LY = CALCULATE(
        SUM([AMOUNT_NET]),
        [YEAR_CW]=[YEAR_CW_LY]
)
```

which works only if instead of [YEAR_CW_LY], the calendar week is hardcoded (e.g. "2023-01"), but does not work if a dynamic filter has to be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `YEAR_CW` as it is:

```
AMOUNT_NET_LY = CALCULATE(
    SUM([AMOUNT_NET]),
    net[YEAR_CW] = CONCATENATE(LEFT(MAX([YEAR_CW]), 4) - 1,CONCATENATE("-",RIGHT(MAX([YEAR_CW]), 2)))
)
```

Comment: YEAR_CW is not a month but a Calendar Week , so a String in the format YYYY-WW. PREVIOUSYEAR() requires a date as parameter, doesn't work on a string.

Comment: In that case i update the answer accordingly